# Is there a way to load an Excel file through Apache POI when the sheet names have invalid characters in them

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am being provided with Excel files that seem to have been generated outside of excel and often have '[' or ']' in one of the worksheet names.

POI doesn't seem to load these files, just throws an error, how can I make Apache-poi load these files and strip out the invalid characters?

Comment: What happens if you try to load them with Apache POI? Does it work? Fail? What messages? etc

Comment: you just want to rename a file why do you do it using apache poi?

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear how POI throw error while file loading in your case.

But xlsx has simple [format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). So you can unzip file and rename appropriate xml and node in workbook.xml to rename page name directly.